# Sidemenu with Special effect for Android

Tags: android

We have an IOS/Android app that is being redesigned and we're really happy with it,
Since IOS7 we are able to be more creative in terms of UX/UI and it's really wonderful.

My problem is with Android, it IS my favorite platform both in terms of Development possibilities and general ideology but for some reason it's lacking the rich content world of IOS.

We've designed a sidemenu with the [following effect](http://goo.gl/V6OGIM) which is really amazing and we love it, but we can't recreate it for Android, i've consulted with several developers and they all gave me the same answer "it's a system limit".

My question is - Is it possible to recreate those effects in Android, if not then why (what's the actual limit) and if Yes, then what am i missing ?

Comment: you could try using this example as a starting point. The youtube app does this. http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We've designed a sidemenu with the following effect which is really amazing and we love it

You're welcome to your opinion. Personally, that would drive me nuts, and I have no idea what benefit it would give users over a regular navigation drawer.

> Is it possible to recreate those effects in Android

It is unclear what specific effects concern you.

Can you resize content, such as the original content shown in the video? Yes.

Can you slide content, such as the original content shown in the video? Yes.

Can you fade in content, such as the items of the menu? Yes.

All of this is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html). Particularly if you are targeting API Level 14+, [property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) is usually the way to go, and you can try NineOldAndroids for a partial backport of those capabilities if you need to support earlier API levels.

If I missed concerns of yours, please comment, or perhaps edit your question.

Comment: When i said it's "really amazing" i was referring to personal taste, as most of our users are IOS based we preferred giving the "Home away from home" feeling.
My question was just that - is the fact that no one is adapting it (or porting it) means there's a limit/problem in that or because it's simply a matter of usability.

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein: "i was referring to personal taste" -- so was I. Beyond that, though, nothing should be stopping you from building that UI if you want, though it may not be easy depending upon how you planned on structuring your code (e.g., activities vs. fragments). The low-level plumbing is there. "because it's simply a matter of usability" -- I'd phrase it more as "because it's not the norm for an Android app", particularly since there are design guidelines for this, as mentioned in another answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

To put it bluntly, user experience.
Providing an experience consistent with the Android operating system is a Priority for Google and by placing some limitations on the way you develop the UI of your app it can ensure an experience that is familiar from app to app.

You can see the UI guidelines here:

http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html

Out of interest have you had your app approved by Apple yet?

Also.. Android does allow you to use a "Sliding Drawer" menu which is very similar to your effect which you could use to meet your goals (without the effect of course).

Comment: The app was already approved by apple - yes. 
as far as normal side menu (Navigation Drawer) for android - this is what we've ended up doing, but while it's working just fine it lacks the "WOW" effect the original design had.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below mentioned git project. It has so many slide menu styles/animations. You can use the one you want or customize as per your need.

**https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu**

Check the below android app for the above mentioned GIT project

**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example**